# Spawning enemies in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to make my enemies appear from top using 'spawn' while rotating on itself.

But I received this error:

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>   spawnScript.addEnemy () (at Assets/Scripts/spawnScript.cs:21)

Below is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spawnScript : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform[] spawnPoints;
public GameObject enemy;
public float spawnTime = 5f;
public float spawnDelay = 3f; 

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    InvokeRepeating ("addEnemy", spawnDelay, spawnTime);

}

void addEnemy() {
    // Instantiate a random enemy.
    int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
    Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem: `public Transform[] spawnPoints;`

The `spawnPoints` variable is declared as public which means that you want to fill it up through the Editor. You  failed to do that and the size is still **0**. When the size is `0`, `Random.Range` will do this `Random.Range(0,0)` and will return `0`. When you feed `0` as index to `spawnPoints` variable, it will throw that error because there is nothing in that `spawnPoints`. You must set the size.

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

This is what it is supposed to look like:

[image]

Notice how I dragged transforms to the `spawnPoints` array slots on my second screenshot. If you don't do that, expect to get `NullException` error.

If you don't want to get that error without seting the size then check if `spawnPoints.Length > 0` before using it.

```
if (spawnPoints.Length > 0)
{
    int spawnPointIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
    Instantiate(enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
}
```

By making the `spawnPoints` a `public` it is assumed that you want to set the `size` from the Editor. You can also set the `size` from script but make it a `private` variable first so that you won't run into issues:

```
void Start()
{
    //Set the size to 3 then fill it up
    spawnPoints = new Transform[3];
    spawnPoints[0] = yourPint1;
    spawnPoints[1] = yourPint2;
    spawnPoints[2] = yourPint3;
}
```

Comment: Thankss! I amended my scripts but i received these 2 errors: 

Assertion failed: TLS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD, underlying allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD has unfreed allocations
UnityEditor.AssetModificationProcessorInternal:OnWillSaveAssets(String[], String[]&, String[]&, Int32)

Assets/Scripts/spawnScript.cs(18,20): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to `UnityEngine.Transform'

Comment: Hi, there is nothing complicated in my answer. You don't even have to modify your code so use your original code from your question. **Just change the size like I did in the second screenshot from my answer.**.

Comment: Hii, i got it just right :) Thanks! But my enemy just appear 1 and static. However, i can see the clones are there, but they are not appearing in my game. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: That's a total different issue. When your question is answered and solved, you [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer then ask **new** question about your new issue. This answer is just here to answer the error in your question not solve your whole program problem. Make sure to provide enough detail to help you in your new question

Comment: @MariamSyafiqahSaidi You should accept the answer (in the left top corner you can see an icon to press) so the question is marked as solved for other users

Answer (score 0):

Error here - `int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);`

You should write - `Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length - 1)`

Comment: Dear, I have amended my script and the same error still appearing. Do you have any other ideas on my scripting errors? Thanks! :)

Comment: @dlarukov It has nothing to do with `Random.Range` and providing `spawnPoints.Length` is actually the correct way to do it not `spawnPoints.Length - 1` since the second parameter of the Random function is exclusive.